# What to do about a commonly misused tag for a deprecated tool?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [typescript-typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-typings) has the following usage guidance:

> DO NOT USE IT AS A SYNONYM OF TYPES. Use for questions on typings, a package for managing TypeScript definitions. It uses typings.json, which can resolve to the Typings Registry, GitHub, NPM, Bower, HTTP, and local files. The package is now deprecated.

As far as I can tell for the past few years it has not been used as it should be... So what are we supposed to do about it? Currently, there's ~4.6k questions, most of them being tagged incorrectly with [typescript-typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-typings). I think there's a few actions we could take:

- Deprecate or [blacklist/block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/blocked-tags/info) the tag. Since the tool is deprecated, we should not really be seeing many new questions with this tool. We could probably create a new tag [typescript-typings-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-typings-tool) and re-tag all the old questions that were using the tag correctly.
- Re-tag all incorrectly tagged questions (which is quite a lot of work).
- Rewrite the usage guidance/tag info and make [typescript-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-types) a synonym. This however, means that the old questions using the typings tool that the tag was originally for are now incorrectly tagged...
- Sweep it under the rug and pretend this problem doesn't exist.

Obviously, this isn't really a good candidate for [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), but I really want something to be done about this. Even the tag info says what to do instead:

> Use for questions about the now deprecated typings package.
>
> Do not use as a synonym of "types", use [typescript-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-types) or [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types) instead. > If your question is about type definitions, use [typescript-definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-definitions) instead.
> Also consider using more specific tags like [typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics) depending on the
> topic of the question.
>
> If your question concerns the project that replaced typings, use [definitelytyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definitelytyped) instead.

So another promising option would be to rewrite the usage guidance to be more direct, like this excerpt from the tag info. Unfortunately, most people don't read the usage guidance before tagging their questions, but this could help with a few cases. Just for reference, here's how it looks now, when trying to add the tag:

[image]

I think the problem is that it only says "DO NOT USE", and people don't know what *else* to use. Maybe a subtle addition like "USE THE TAG typescript-types INSTEAD" would be more helpful? There's probably other tags with a similar problem, but I'm [only active in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/topusers) so this is the only one I noticed.

Comment: "*I think the problem is that it only says "DO NOT USE", and people don't know what else to use.*" Almost always it an issue of people just not reading the description on tags. Maybe if we made users find tags based on searching for and selecting based on the descriptions instead of the tag names...

Comment: To give users a bit of credit here, `typescript-typings` _sounds_ like it should naturally apply to _typings in TypeScript_... I'd vote for a fifth option (in combo with clean-up): rename the tag to be more apparently about a package, rather than sounding like a language feature.

Comment: Maybe `typings-typescript-package`? `typings-ts-defn-manager`? `typings-definition-manager-ts`? There's gotta be a good option that's less generic and easy to confuse than the current.

Comment: While I agree with most of this in one way or another, I'd argue *"Since the tool is deprecated, we should not really be seeing new questions with this tool."* is pretty short-sighted, people use old things all the time.

Comment: "Deprecate or blacklist/block the tag" - tags cannot be deprecated, and blacklisting is a last-resort manual procedure initiated only for *very, very bad* tags. If the tag attracts on-topic questions but is misused, it's a call for a cleanup effort at maximum.

Comment: I'd go for splitting out a new tag specifically for the package, retagging questions that are about the package with that tag, then updating the proposal to be a [meta-tag:retag-request] so as the rest of the questions are retagged in bulk. A good idea would be to coordinate the effort with the [Burnination HQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq) room. If anyone is willing to spearhead such an action, be my guest - unfortunately, I lack time to spare these days to undertake it myself.

Comment: As the author of the notice (as well as of the tag wiki itself): "DO NOT USE" and "use for" are widely standard templates for excerpts. Tag excerpts have a strict character limit + the modal popping up for users is even more restrictive in terms of size, so corners had to be cut - it's been a while since I'd made the excerpt, but if I recall correctly, this was the reason why I only included what to use in the wiki. If you believe both "do not use" and "use for" can fit - no objections from me.

Comment: "typescript-typings-tool" for a rename, maybe. It is exceptionally awkward that the name of the thing is maximally ambiguous. By the looks of it, it is used as a build tool and not so much as a package for programming.

Answer (score 3):

Deprecated tool or deprecated tag? There is no requirement on SO that questions must always be about the latest and greatest technology. Having tags for old technologies is not a problem.

- Questions about deprecated technologies are on-topic.
- Questions that were asked before some technology went deprecated are on-topic. They should not be re-tagged.

Answering a new question by suggesting a deprecated technology is however a reason for down-voting that answer, unless the question explicitly asked about old technology.

---

For the specific tag, all of the suggested alternatives [typescript-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-types), [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types), [typescript-definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-definitions), [typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics), [definitelytyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definitelytyped) suffer from poor tag usage wikis. So if you believe that [typescript-typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-typings) is misused, step one would be to offer proper tag wikis for the alternatives. For example at a bare minimum, such a tag wiki should probably mention that they should always be used together with [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript).

[types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types) specifically is a useless, ambiguous tag that probably shouldn't be used for any purpose.

"DO NOT USE" etc shouldn't be added to a tag wiki just because the technology went deprecated. Tag wikis are not recommendations of which technology to use.

Comment: "Having tags for old technologies is not a problem." - in fact it is perfect. For one you can put them on the exclude list, like I did with AngularJS.

Comment: The reason the tag should not be used is not because the technology is deprecated, but because the tag is useless for the purpose of helping people find relevant Q&As about the topic.